# Unrecognized arguments in graphql mutation

Tags: javascript, meteor, graphql, apollo

I'm curretly following [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=z4TKqxLKE6c&list=PLLnpHn493BHFTDL9M1PKnxQwBwOZ8J-h4&index=13) on Meteor/Apollo/GraphQL, and having huge troubles to make a mutation with arguments/variables. Here is my code and some notes at the bottom !

### The code

#### Schema

```
type Resolution {
    _id: String!
    name: String!
}

type Mutation {
    createResolution(name: String!): Resolution
}
```

#### Resolver

```
import Resolutions from './resolutions'

export default {
    Query: {
        resolutions() {
            return Resolutions.find({}).fetch()
        }
    },
    Mutation: {
        createResolution(obj, args, context) {
            console.log('hey i get here')
        }
    }
}
```

#### The component using the mutation

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import gql from 'graphql-tag'
import { graphql } from 'react-apollo'

const createResolutionQuery = gql`
    mutation createResolution($name: String!) {
        createResolution(name: $name) {
            _id
        }
    }
`

class ResolutionForm extends Component {
    submitForm = () => {
        this.props
            .createResolution({
                variables: {
                    name: this.name.value
                }
            })
            .then(d => console.log('data received'))
            .catch(e => console.log(e))
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <input type="text" ref={input => (this.name = input)} />
                <button onClick={this.submitForm}>Submit</button>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default graphql(createResolutionQuery, {
    name: 'createResolution'
})(ResolutionForm)
```

### What i know

- When i try to send my query to the server, i get an http 400 error, and i get the following graphql error :  "Unknown argument "name" on field "createResolution" of type "Mutation"."
- The createResolution is available in my graphiQL but does not show any arguments in the doc.
- It's stipulated in the tutorial that changing the .graphql schema does not trigger meteor server reloading, to apply change i have to modify my  "register-api" file which is responsible for making the executable schema and create the apollo server with it. I made fake change to trigger it but it did not changed anything.
- I tried to relaunch the server after erasing my browser's cache with no result.

So I think my problem is with the mutation arguments (brilliant deduction I know), but I can't figure out where is the typo or where I'm missing something. Help from somebody with a fresh look is welcome, thanks :)

## Edit

Reinstall npm packages solved the issue.

Comment: try it with `this.props.createResolution(this.name.value)...`, i think that you don't have to pass the `variables` config since you're not using the apollo client.

Comment: Hey, thanks, i tried but my component is indeed expecting this object with the variables prop. I don't think the issue come from cleint side but from the server related files where my arguments are not recognized.

Comment: schema looks good. can you put your repo on github?

Comment: Yep [here it is](https://github.com/halkeand/meteor-apollo-tuto) !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All looks good I made a small change and added it as a pull request to your github repo.

```
createResolution(obj, {name}, context) {
        console.log('hey i get here')
        const id = Resolutions.insert({
            name,
        })
        return Resolutions.findOne(id)
    }
```

Running on my machine I get no errors.

Comment: I merged and tried with destructuring but the same error is always appearing on my computer, what is really confusing me is the fact that queries are working fine but not mutation and since it's using the same protocol, i guess it's not an HTTP misconfiguration otherwise none of queries/mutation would works. In the mean time the code seems not to be error prone since it's working on your computer... So what could be the remainning error hideout ?

Comment: Have you tried checking out the repository in a fresh folder run `meteor npm i` and then `meteor` then that way we have both done exactly the same thing. Let me know what happens, please.

Comment: No, I dumbly pasted the changes but i just restarted from a fresh folder now and everything works fine. I guess I had issues with npm packages downloading and did not noticed it, I will carefully watch them from now on. Thanks for your help !

Comment: Great news, I am really pleased I could help!